# Javascript (with Phaser) error showing colour of game -Brackets

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework, adobe-brackets

I am having problems in JS (and HTML) using Phaser to change a game's background colour. I'm using brackets version 1.3 and using the Live Preview feature to see my code (using Chrome). I have not had this problem before, although I have not used Phaser in brackets since upgrading to Windows 10. Also, I have just noticed that my URL in the preview has changed from being the file destination- e.g. "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\HTML5 Games(Phaser)\Simple Jump Game\index.html" - to a strange IP-style URL (But it is not my IPV4, IPV6 or Default Gateway). It shows - "http://127.0.0.1:55312/index.html". I am following a textbook (Although making a different game to it- I haven't used Phaser for a while so using it to remind me!) And have copied and pasted from the textbook into my files and I'm still getting an error. These are my files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

    <title>Simple Jump game</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>

    <!--Script files-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/phaser.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/main.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
     <div id="gameDiv"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

And my JS:

```
 //The main state of our game
var mainState = { 

    preload: function() { //A function which loads everything (e.g assets),       before the game starts


    },

    create: function() { //A function which physicly adds everything into     our game(e.g sprites)
         game.stage.backgroundColor = '#84B6F7'

         game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
    },

    update: function() { //A function which is called 60 times per second and holds all of the game's logic.


    },

};


//Create a new game, using our 'gameDiv' and store it in 'game'
var game = new Phaser.Game(500, 340, Phaser.AUTO, 'gameDiv');


//Add the mainState to our game (as 'main') and start it.
game.add.state('main', mainState);
game.state.start('main');
```

BTW I included  **my**  code not the code from the textbook (Although they should be the same). The textbook is 'Discover Phaser' by Thomas Palef

EDIT: The background colour holds the textbooks colour, the comment next to it has my background colour in. I used the textbook's colour to make sure there isn't an issue with my colour- there isn't.

Comment: Could you print your error?

Comment: Where is the error shown - in the browser or in Brackets? Which Phaser version are you using?

Comment: There is no error being shown. It is just that on the page the colour of the game (the 'gameDiv' element) is black- instead of the blue.

Comment: BTW- All of my other Phaser projects don't do this and the URL's are the file destinations- I'm really stumped on what it is.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I have found my error! I cross-checked this code with another project and found my error! In the second to last line I did 'game.add.state' whereas it should have been 'game.state.add'!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! Silly mistake.

I did:

```
game.add.state('main', mainState);
```

instead of:

```
game.state.add('main', mainState);
```

Thanks for everyone's time!

Answer (score 2):

An answer to your other question - 127.0.0.1 means 'localhost' or 'this computer'; most propbably Brackets runs its own server, which, when ran locally, can be accessed at this address. It may be fine for now to access index.html by its file URL if you're just running some basic set-up code, but once you begin loading assets (images, sounds and so on), your browser will most probably begin throwing cross-origin request errors and you will need to access the game via a local server.

Comment: Thanks so much for that! I was quite confused as it appeared on my latest project that was working fine. It's great to know.